# append array to xml object

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

i have the following input

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "name": "value1"
        },
        {
            "name": "value2"
        },
        {
            "name": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

and would like the following output

```
<a>
    <b />
    <c>value1</c>   
    <c>value2</c>   
    <c>value3</c>    
</a>
```

the closest i can get is this

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>value1</c>
    <c>value2</c>
    <c>value3</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

with this dataweave

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
---

a: b: (payload.*array map {c: $.name})
```

any assistance appreciated thank you

and for extra points .. if anyone can help generate the following with the above sample json payload

```
<a>
    <b />
    <c>value1</c>
    <d>e</d>    
    <c>value2</c>
    <d>e</d>        
    <c>value3</c>
    <d>e</d>         
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this approach:

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
---

a : { 
 b: {}
}
 ++ {
  (payload.*array map {c: $.name})
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, you can get your second expected output:

#### Script

```
    %dw 2.0
    output xml writeDeclaration=false
    ---

    a : { 
    b:''
    }
    ++ {
    (payload.array map 
    {
      c: $.name,
      d:'e'
    })
    }
```

#### Output

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c>value1</c>
  <d>e</d>
  <c>value2</c>
  <d>e</d>
  <c>value3</c>
  <d>e</d>
</a>
```